# Automatically Color a Word in Sentence

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets or Excel is there a way to color a word in a sentence when it matches the word in the previous cell in the same row? I know that I can use the `IF` function and conditional formatting to highlight the total cell which contains that word, but what I need is just to color the matching word.

[image: This is an illustration of what is required]

[This is an example sheet of what I want](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-yrNmYE9tkFbxeHfT0v5MBuTtxopMgc-KGxP9fHDmHU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues();
  const resetColor = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("#000000").build();
  const style = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setForegroundColor("red").build();
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(([, , c], i) => {
    const textAr = c.getText().split(" ");
    const a = textAr[values[i][1] - 1];
    if (a == values[i][0]) {
      const start = [...Array(values[i][1] - 1)].reduce((n, _, j) => n += textAr[j].length, 0) + values[i][1] - 1;
      const temp = c.copy().setTextStyle(resetColor).setTextStyle(start, start + a.length, style);
      return [temp.build()];
    }
    return [c];
  });
  range.offset(0, 2, richTextValues.length, 1).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "A2:C", and the text style of the values of column "C" is modified using the values of columns "A" and "B".
- And, in this script, when the script is run, the font color is reset, and new font color is set.
- If you want to keep the current text style, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const temp = c.copy().setTextStyle(resetColor).setTextStyle(start, start + a.length, style);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const temp = c.copy().setTextStyle(start, start + a.length, style);
    ```

#### Testing:

When this script is used to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet and values, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue)
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)